# How do I link a method to a property in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I am learning MVC and I'm currently using the MvcMusicStore tutorial, but adding some extras and more features.

I have a method which calculates the total price, by multiplying quantity by unit price.

I have a property in the model called `TotalPrice`, to which I want this method 'attached' to such that `TotalPrice`'s value comes from this method.

The name of the method is `GetTotal()`

My model is as follows:

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }


    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities();
    public decimal GetTotal()
    {

        decimal? total = (from s in db.OrderDetails
                          where s.OrderDetailId == OrderDetailId
                          select (decimal?)Quantity * UnitPrice).Sum();
        return total ?? decimal.Zero;
    }
}
```

I want the value returned by the method to populate the `TotalPrice` field, which currently is `null` because there is no method linked to it.

How can I make `TotalPrice` get its value from `GetTotal()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that TotalPrice is a property you can call the method from the property itself:

```
public decimal TotalPrice 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    return GetTotal();
  }
}
```

However, I wouldn't suggest trying to pull the total price from the database when you should be able to use the data from the model so you should do this:

```
public decimal TotalPrice 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    return Quantity * UnitPrice;
  }
}
```

If you need to do a sum of all items in the order then you need to implement something like this in your order class:

```
public class Order 
{ 
  List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;}
  ....


  public decimal TotalPrice 
  { 
    get 
    {
      decimal total = 0;
      foreach (var o in OrderDetails) 
      {
        total += o.TotalPrice;
      }
      return total;
    }

  }
}
```

**Update**

Or even simpler (you need to import System.Linq):

```
public class Order 
{ 
  List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;}
  ....


  public decimal TotalPrice 
  { 
    get 
    {
      OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.TotalPrice);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This seems simple. Just want to clarify, I already have another class called `Order`. So do I do this linq in that class, and not in my `OrderDetails` class?

Comment: Yes, the Order class (or whatever you have named it) is where you will want the LINQ expression to sum all of the TotalPrice properties from OrderDetails. The TotalPrice property in the OrderDetails class simply needs to multiply the quantity by the unit price.

Comment: Thank you, its working, but I think something Is wrong with my linq in the `GetTotal()` method.

There's something wrong the values. eg: `Quantity` is 3 and `UnitPrice` is 275. The value that gets saved into `TotalPrice` should be 825, but somehow 43850 appears.

Comment: As I said in the answer you shouldn't be trying to get the total from the database in your orderdetails class (or in fact from any model directly). You should look at creating a service or repository to access the data USING your models

Comment: Have a look here if your just getting started... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. You might need to google Entity Framework Service pattern for more info